# How to detect if a Type is a List?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Suppose I have access to the type of a field using reflection:

```
FieldInfo item;
Type type = item.FieldType;
```

I want to know if `type` is a generic `List` or not, How can I do that? I need something like as follows, But it does not work:

```
if (type == typeof(List<>))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Type type = item.FieldType;
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is:

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines whether the given <paramref name="type"/> is a generic list
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type">The type to evaluate</param>
/// <returns><c>True</c> if is generic otherwise <c>False</c></returns>
public static bool IsGenericList(this Type type)
{
    if (!type.IsGenericType) { return false; }

    var typeDef = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    if (typeDef == typeof(List<>) || typeDef == typeof(IList<>)) { return true; }
    return false;
}
```